# Maven surefire permgen out of space

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, permgen

Tried many ways to increase permgen size but no luck.

I am using following configuration in my pom

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=216m</argLine>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Tried "set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m" in command line, no luck as well.

[image: maven Surefire booter forkedBooter]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your configuration is slightly incorrect. You don't need the [`<includes>`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) element, [`<argLine>`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) should be directly under `<configuration>`.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=216m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```